React TS boolean class method returns undefined, but works when the method code is placed directly inside conditional rendering
I have a folder with some files and subfolders to render. If the folder is empty I want to render an EmptyFolder component. This is my FolderDTO class:
import { NoteDTO } from "../Note/NoteDTO";

export class FolderDTO {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    subFolderIds: number[];
    subFolderNames: string[];
    notes: NoteDTO[];

    constructor(id: number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = '';
        this.subFolderIds = [];
        this.subFolderNames = [];
        this.notes = [];
    }

    isEmpty(): boolean {
        return this.notes.length === 0 && this.subFolderIds.length === 0;

    }
}

Here is how I handle the conditional rendering:
{folder?.isEmpty && <EmptyFolder /> }

Doing this won't render the EmptyFolder, and when i log the output of the isEmpty method is is undefined. But if is place the code of the isEmpty method instead it works and the EmptyFolder component shows up.
{folder?.notes.length === 0 && folder.subFolderIds.length === 0 && <EmptyFolder /> }

Why is it that the exact same condition won't work with a class method?

It seems you forgot to call your method like this folder?.isEmpty() or use getter like get isEmpty() in class.

I have also tried this and I get a folder.isEmpty is not a function error.
